# ArrayList and connection different classes

Tags: java, class, arraylist

Im pretty new to Java. I'm trying to connect these classes together. The `Go` class, is the main class, that should end up running the program. According to Eclipse, the program doesn't contain any errors, but while running, the outprint is blank.

The Go class:

```
public class Go {           
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        Data klasseObject = new Data();
        klasseObject.infoListe();       
    }
}
```

The `Ansat` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Ansat {    
    public String navn;
    public int alder;

    public Ansat(String navn, int alder, ArrayList<Ansat> ansat){
        this.navn = navn;
        this.alder = alder;         
    }

    public int getAlder() {
        return alder;
    }

    public void setAlder(int alder) {
        this.alder = alder;
    }

    public String getNavn() {
        return navn;
    }

    public void setNavn(String navn) {
        this.navn = navn;
    }
}
```

The `Data` class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Data {
    private ArrayList<Ansat> ansat; 

    public void infoListe(){
        ansat = new ArrayList<Ansat>();
        ansat.add(new Ansat("Hej", 123, ansat));
    }

    public ArrayList<Ansat> getAnsat() {
        return ansat;
    }       
}
```

Comment: That might be because you are not outputting anything

Comment: I've added informations to the ArrayList, through the Data class though. I want the program to output "Hej, 123", as written in the Data class.

Comment: Try a `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(klasseObject.getAnsat()));`

Comment: Add this **System.out.println(klasseObject.getAnsat().get(0));** to your main method and see what you get in the output. You are not printing anything.

Comment: Use S.O.P to print the output.
You have your getter and setter in place, so wont be a much of a problem.

Comment: @Raf, the output still isn't 100% correct. The output is "Ansat@6d06d69c"

Comment: @EmilMørkeberg see the answer/s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend just two modifications for you to get a proper readable output.

Add the following method to your `Ansat` class

```
//modify the returned string however you want it to appear
public String toString() {
    return navn + " , " + alder; 
}
```

and then add this line in your main method of `Go` class (last statement)

```
System.out.println(klasseObject.getAnsat().get(0).toString());
```

The `toString()` class that is added to the `Ansat` is overriding the toString() method for Ansat meaning that it allows you to print the fields of Ansat class the way you want it and whenever you invoke `toString()` on object of Ansat then it will pretty print it for you such as below:

```
Hej , 123
```

You can update the `toString()` method to print it however you want.

If you wish to have more than one element in your ArrayList then you have to do the following changes (but, I do want state that you are not doing this the right way):

```
Data klasseObject = new Data();
klasseObject.infoListe(); 

Data klasseObject2 = new Data(); 
klasseObject.infoListe(); 

Data klasseObject3 = new Data(); 
klasseObject.infoListe(); 

for(Ansat s: klasseObject.getAnsat()) 
    System.out.println(s.toString());
```

And this changes to your Data class

```
public void infoListe(){
    if(ansat != null) {
        ansat.add(new Ansat("Hej", 123, ansat));
    } else {
        ansat = new ArrayList<Ansat>();
        ansat.add(new Ansat("Hej", 123, ansat));
    }
}
```

If I were to review your code and suggest improvements, then I would do the following changes in your classes (copy/paste the following code Go.java file and run it):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Go {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // running below creates an ArrayList<Ansat> that is inside KlasseObject
        Data klasseObject = new Data();

        // creates one Ansat(Hey,123) and add it to list
        klasseObject.setData("Hey", 123);

        // creates one Ansat(Raf,555) and add it to list
        klasseObject.setData("Raf", 555);

        // creates one Ansat(X-men,999) and add it to list
        klasseObject.setData("X-men", 999);

        //as many classes as you want, it would add them all to the list
        //of klasseObject 

        // now that we set three Ansats, we will retrieve the list and print
        // them all
        for (Ansat s : klasseObject.getAnsatList())
            System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
}

class Ansat {
    public String navn;
    public int alder;

    //remove the array list from constructor, not needed
    public Ansat(String navn, int alder) {
        this.navn = navn;
        this.alder = alder;
    }

    public int getAlder() {
        return alder;
    }

    public void setAlder(int alder) {
        this.alder = alder;
    }

    public String getNavn() {
        return navn;
    }

    public void setNavn(String navn) {
        this.navn = navn;
    }

    //overrided toString method to pretty-print Ansat object
    public String toString() {
        return navn + " , " + alder;
    }
}

class Data {
    private ArrayList<Ansat> ansat;

    // added the constructor for Data to initialize Data with empty list
    public Data() {
        ansat = new ArrayList<Ansat>();
    }

    //replaced infoListe to setData and added args to it so you can 
    //pass them from main method
    public void setData(String name, int age) {
        // every time setData is called a new Ansat is added to list
        Ansat a = new Ansat(name, age);
        ansat.add(a);
    }

    public ArrayList<Ansat> getAnsatList() {
        return ansat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically your answer worked well, thank you. But if I add more data to my ArrayList, it still only prints "Hej , 123"

Comment: You need to loop through the list. Let me update the code with examples.

Comment: @EmilMørkeberg I have modified my answer to show how you can add more than one Ansat object in the list and then print them. Modifying your code to allow addition of more than one Ansat object is tricky but, I showed in example above. I also modified all your codes just now to help you easily add Ansat objects. Copy/paste the last snippet of code and run it and see how things work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Output the contents of `ArrayList` to console

```
    public class Go {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Data klasseObject = new Data();
        klasseObject.infoListe();   

        for(Ansat ansat : getAnsat()){
           system.out.println(ansat.getNavn(), ansat.getAlder());
         }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the process what you have followed is perfectly correct,But your getting blank because your not printing the arraylist, hence your getting blank output. Just add the below line and you will see the correct output.

```
public void infoListe(){

        ansat = new ArrayList<Ansat>();
        ansat.add(new Ansat("Hej", 123, ansat));
        System.out.println(ansat);

    }
```

or in the main function just use it like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Data klasseObject = new Data();
        klasseObject.infoListe();
        System.out.println(klasseObject.getAnsat());
    }
```

Even iterating over array list will fetch you the output -

```
 for (Ansat ansatLoop : klasseObject.getAnsat()) {
            System.out.println(ansatLoop.getAlder() + ":"
                    + ansatLoop.getNavn());
        }
```

I hope this would solve your query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The output still isn't 100% correct. The output is: "[Ansat@6d06d69c]"

Comment: for (Ansat ansatLoop : klasseObject.getAnsat()) {
            System.out.println(ansatLoop.getAlder() + ":"
                    + ansatLoop.getNavn());
        }

Comment: Try the above code in main method so you would get the answer

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working Perfectly! It has no

```
       System.out.println();
```

anywhere in the methods that run.
If you modify the method infoListe() to add a println it will print something out

```
   public void infoListe(){

    ansat = new ArrayList<Ansat>();
    ansat.add(new Ansat("Hej", 123, ansat));
    System.out.println("Element Added to ArrayList"); 




}
```

Comment: It still wont print the result, it will only print: "Element Added to ArrayList".

Comment: @XOR-Manik There is no other line in your original code that prints anything.